# Process 1 loop at a time containing async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I have a program where I need to iterate over several hundred folders. Each folder contains a master xml file that I read and then loop over each element in the file.  My process is to read the directory and get the folders then do a for loop over the folders then I put each element from the master file into an array and do a forEach. Inside the forEach there are 2 asynchronous functions that get called.  Both are mongoDB queries.  The first is to do a lookup to get data for each element and then at the end I do an update to mongoDB.

The problem I'm running into is that because the the async functions are getting queued and waiting for the loops to finish before executing, the process is running out of memory.  In this case there are probably about 100,000 elements so it's too much to handle.

What I'm trying to figure out is if there's a better way to do this or if there's a way to process a single folder completely before going to the next folder.

This is a simplified example of the code structure.

```
fs.readdir(dirname + 'folders', function(err, folders) {
for (var i = 0; i < folders.length; i++) {
    var resources = resources;
    resources.forEach(function(doc) {
        //do lookup in mongodb
        getStandardsArray(doc, function(standardsArray, origItem) {
            //In callback update item in mongodb
            db.collection(collection).update( {"id": id}, origItem, { upsert: true}, function(err, numberAffected) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
}

getStandardsArray = function(item, standards, callback) {
sharedDb.collection("standards").findOne({"id": formatGUID(standards[i])}, function(err, doc) {
    callback(standardsArray, item);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code your own loop using a recursive function; that way you can wait until all callbacks/promises have resolved before moving on to the next folder:

```js
const folders = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var folderIndex = -1;

function processNextFolder() {
  if (++folderIndex === folders.length) return; // done
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`Folder ${folders[folderIndex]} processed`);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  }).then(() => {
    processNextFolder();
  })
}

console.log("Starting...");
processNextFolder();
```

Comment: This code is still having the same problem.  processNextFolder is being called before the mongdb calls have run so it's still just queuing up until it runs out of memory.

Comment: @RUEMACHINE That's a problem with your implementation though, not my proposed solution. You need to make sure that `processNextFolder()` is called in the "has finished" callback of your last folder operation.